# Como hacer una relacion con dependencia de dos tablas en mysql?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Buen dia, tengo la duda de como hacer una relacion de dos tablas donde: 
la columna n_empleado de la tabla entrada_registro no puda ser llenada sin que ese mismo dato (numero de trabajador identico) exista previamente en la tabla registro.
eso por cuestiones de seguridad ya que estoy creando un sistema de registro
en teoria hacer el registro de mis trabajadores, y cuando chequen su entrada y salida sepa que ya estan registrados y si no es asi enviar condicional en PHP

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si la relación está bien hecha, MySQL no va a permitir que el campo sea llenado si no es un registro que ya existe en la otra tabla (llave foránea).

Answer (score 2):

Te recomiendo crear una llave foránea, así:

```
CREATE TABLE registro (
    n_empleado INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    /* resto de campos de la tabla */
);

CREATE TABLE entrada_salidas (
    registro INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    n_empleado INT NOT NULL,
    /* resto de campos */
    FOREIGN KEY (n_empleado) REFERENCES registro(n_empleado)
);
```