# Relacionar 2 bases de datos

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Espero que me puedan ayudar:

Tengo 2 bases de datos y necesito vincular un dato de la `BD1` a la `BD2`.

Actualmente estoy trabajando con `mysql workbench`, ¿será posible hacer la relación de una BD a otra?

Comment: Bienvenido, 1- ¿Que has intentado? [Edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/42728) y coloca lo que has hecho. 2- ¿No has intentado nada? No somos Google, nos solucionamos problemas que tengamos en cuando a código, mas no hacemos tareas. 3- la pregunta es duplicada.

Comment: [Acá la pregunta a la cual esta relacionada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/11333/como-hacer-una-relacion-con-dependencia-de-dos-tablas-en-mysql)

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Como hacer una relacion con dependencia de dos tablas en mysql?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/11333/como-hacer-una-relacion-con-dependencia-de-dos-tablas-en-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

Puedes implicar más de una base de datos en la misma consulta, sólo tienes que calificarla ejemplo

```
SELECT 
    base1.*, base2.*
FROM 
    nombreBase1.nombreTabla base1
INNER JOIN 
    nombreBase2.nombreTabla base2 
    ON base1.id=base2.id
```

Answer (score -1):

Como yo lo veo, lo mas sencillo sería crear una vista en la BD2 con los datos de la BD1. Luego creas la relación desde la vista a la tabla en tu BD2.

Un saludo.